# C# Use if in foreach

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

The Code below resets form labels to "0". Out of curiosity, I am trying to figure out how to access only certain items rather than every item in the List. The foreach function works great here but in other parts of the code I would like to access and modify these objects diferently

For example how could I set every other field to "0" or set only the last or first three to some value, etc.

```
// Set the form Labels to "0"
private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create List of Labels for modifying form
    new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 }.ForEach(p => p.Text = "0");
}
```

Thank You

Update:

Well after lots of reading and testing I came back to the most basic method for selecting every other item in the list.

```
        // Set the form Labels to "0"
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create List of Labels for modifying form
        List<Label> lbl = new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 };
        int x =1; //  Set to get every other label. 0 = even, 1 = odd
        while (x < lbl.Count)
        {
            lbl[x].Text = "0";
            x = x + 2;
        }
```

@Jonathan Wood is there a method to this with the
 `items.ForEach(p => { some code(), p.Text = "0"; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delegate that you pass to `ForEach()` can be enclosed in curly braces, which allows you to define more complex logic such as `if` statements.

```
items.ForEach(p => { if (p != null) p.Text = "0"; });
```

You can even define your delegate as a separate method and just pass that.

However, I wonder about your approach. Is this a winforms app? Why not just do a regular loop that loops through controls on the form? Then the additional table won't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks JWThe original idea was that since four different buttons affect these labels to one degree or another that using an array type method would allow for a more modular type code. That is one list to be used for several different setups.

Comment: So why unaccept this answer? Seems to answer precisely what you asked.

Comment: It was a great solution if I wanted to choose items based on their contents. The .Take() and .Reverse().Take() also were a solution of sorts. After some more research I guess my real question was more about array access. Finally I realized that some of the programming could best be handled by form layout. All in I learned a lot but not sure where to put the check mark. At first I was trying to give more than one. Do check marks award cred somehow?

Comment: @WCoaster: Well your question was title `C# Use if in foreach` but whatever. Looks like you haven't accepted any answer. I hope that works well for you on stackoverflow.

Comment: Again do accepted answers bestow credit to giver? Also please see revised question. Is there a way to do that in the method you showed? You mentioned "more complex logic" is there a way to move through the index in a ForEach statement or the loop a better method like you said originally?

Comment: The point is that everyone can see what percent of answers you accept. I'll leave you to figure out what percent will make the most people try to answer your future questions. No, there is no way to determine the index of the item from a `ForEach()` delegate short of incrementing your own counter, which defeats the the benefits of `ForEach()`. In this case, a simply `for` loop may make the most sense.

Answer (score 3):

To set every other field to "0" you could try the [IEnumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) overload that passes the index of current element to the predicate.

Let's say you want to work on the elements with odd index:

```
new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 }.Where((p, i) => (i & 1) == 1).ToList().ForEach(p => p.Text = "0");
```

Comment: Since when does `i & 1` return a `bool`?

Comment: Ah, excellent this is what I was looking for but still beyond the scope of my learning so far. I was reading about IEnumerable earlier today. guess I didn't make the connection.

Comment: Hmmm compiler does not like the .ForEach after the .Where. Any ideas?

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Label>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach' and no extension method 'ForEach' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Label>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Classtest\Classtest\Form1.cs 69 100 Classtest

Comment: This doesn't work since an `IEnumerable<Label>` does not have a `ForEach` method. You would need to create a new `List<Label>`(f.e. via `ToList()`). But unnecessary since you can use a normal `foreach` loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are right. I was careless once more. Fixed it. This ToList call adds a performace overhead since it creates a new list. I cannot understand why they haven't added the ForEach method to the Enumerable class along with all the other extension methods and instead added it to the List<T> class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

first three:

```
var labels = new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 };
foreach(Label lbl in labels.Take(3))
    lbl.Text = someValue;
```

last three:

```
foreach(Label lbl in labels.Reverse().Take(3))
    lbl.Text = someValue;
```

other labels:

```
var allLabels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();
var otherLabels = allLabels.Except(labels);
foreach(Label lbl in otherLabels)
    lbl.Text = "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Set first 3 to 0

```
new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 }.Take(3).ForEach(p => p.Text = "0");
```

Set last 3 to 0

```
new List<Label>() { lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6 }.Skip(3).Take(3).ForEach(p => p.Text = "0");
```